# JSONDecoder unable to decode an object encoded by JSONEncoder

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I have a requirement to encode/decode snakeCased JSONs. I found that encoder encodes `Value2` object correctly, however decoder fails to decode it. What I do wrong here?

Required Json format:

```
{
  "address_line_1" : "Address",
  "full_name" : "Name",
  "id" : 2
}
```

Code:

```
struct Value1: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let fullName: String
    let addressLine1: String
}

struct Value2: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let fullName: String
    let addressLine_1: String
}

func printJson(_ object: Data) throws {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: object, options: [])
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys])
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}

func encode<T: Encodable>(_ object: T) throws -> Data {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
    return try encoder.encode(object)
}

func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    _ = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
    print("✅ Decoded \(type) from:")
    try printJson(data)
}

do {
    var data: Data

    data = try encode(Value1(id: 1, fullName: "Name", addressLine1: "Address"))
    try decode(Value1.self, from: data)
    

    data = try encode(Value2(id: 2, fullName: "Name", addressLine_1: "Address"))
    _ = try decode(Value1.self, from: data)
    _ = try decode(Value2.self, from: data)
    
} catch {
    print("❌ Failed with error:", error)
}
```

Output:

```
✅ Decoded Value1 from:
{
  "address_line1" : "Address",
  "full_name" : "Name",
  "id" : 1
}
✅ Decoded Value1 from:
{
  "address_line_1" : "Address",
  "full_name" : "Name",
  "id" : 2
}
❌ Failed with error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "addressLine_1", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"addressLine_1\", intValue: nil) (\"addressLine_1\"), with divergent representation addressLine1, converted to address_line_1.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: Because you are using `addressLine_1`, so it expects `addressLine_1 `, but since your encoder keystrategy is snakeCase, it changes it. Don't mix it like that, either use only camelCase for var, and use snake strategy, or use your own CodingKeys.

Answer (score 1):

`convertFromSnakeCase` works correctly and you can can check it in first decode:

```swift
_ = try decode(Value1.self, from: data)
```

After that, when you try to decode the same `data` but with `Value2` type it surely fails as it expects different property name. This is your encoded snake case JSON:

```json
{
  "address_line_1" : "Address",
  "full_name" : "Name",
  "id" : 2
}
```

After decoder conversion `address_line_1` becomes `addressLine1` (the same applies to `full_name`) which fits properties of `Value1`. If you try to decode the same data for `Value2` it fails as property name requires `addressLine_1`.

In your case, optimal strategy would be to use custom coding keys, like this:

```swift
struct Value2: Codable {
    private enum Value2CodingKey: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case addressLine1 = "address_line_1"
    }

    let id: Int
    let fullName: String
    let addressLine1: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without using custom coding keys, but custom coding strategy instead, so coders handle _ before numbers as well.
So that `addressLine1` encodes to `address_line_1`, and `address_line_1` decodes to `addressLine1`

Usage:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCaseWithNumbers

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCaseWithNumbers
```

Coder implementation:

```
extension JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy {
    static var convertToSnakeCaseWithNumbers: JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy {
        .custom { codingKeys -> CodingKey in
            let stringValue = codingKeys.last!.stringValue
            let newKey = AnyKey(stringValue: convertToSnakeCase(stringValue))!
            return newKey
        }
    }
    
    private static func convertToSnakeCase(_ stringKey: String) -> String {
        var key = stringKey
        let searchRange = key.index(after: key.startIndex)..<key.endIndex
        let nsRange = key.nsRange(from: searchRange)
        let matches = NSRegularExpression("([A-Z])|([0-9]+)").matches(in: key, options: [], range: nsRange)
        for match in matches.reversed() {
            guard let range = key.range(from: match.range) else { continue }
            key.insert("_", at: range.lowerBound)
        }
        return key.lowercased()
    }
}

extension JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
    static var convertFromSnakeCaseWithNumbers: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
        .custom { (codingKeys) -> CodingKey in
            let stringValue = codingKeys.last!.stringValue
            let newKey = AnyKey(stringValue: convertFromSnakeCase(stringValue))!
            return newKey
        }
    }
    
    private static func convertFromSnakeCase(_ stringKey: String) -> String {
        guard stringKey.contains("_") else {
            return stringKey
        }
        let components = stringKey.split(separator: "_").map({ $0.firstCapitalized })
        return components.joined().firstLowercased
    }
}

private extension NSRegularExpression {
    convenience init(_ pattern: String) {
        do {
            try self.init(pattern: pattern)
        } catch {
            preconditionFailure("Illegal regular expression: \(pattern).")
        }
    }
}

private extension StringProtocol {
    var firstLowercased: String { prefix(1).lowercased() + dropFirst() }
    var firstCapitalized: String { prefix(1).capitalized + dropFirst() }
}

enum AnyKey: CodingKey {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
    
    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .string(let string):
            return string
        case .int(let int):
            return "\(int)"
        }
    }
    
    var intValue: Int? {
        guard case let .int(int) = self else { return nil }
        return int
    }
    
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        guard !stringValue.isEmpty else { return nil }
        self = .string(stringValue)
    }
    
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self = .int(intValue)
    }
}
```